# mode-specific emacs keybindings

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to get `emacs` (23.3 on Arch Linux) to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to the built-in "compile" function when in C-mode (actually CC-mode, which comes built-in as well). So far I've tried the following:

```
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook (define-key c-mode-map (kbd "C-<f12>") 'compile))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

and:

```
(eval-after-load 'c-mode
  '(define-key c-mode-map (kbd "C-<f12>") 'compile))
```

But neither works; I get `<C-f12> is undefined`. Based on what I've read [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#CC-Hooks), [here](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2008/12/binding-keys.html), and [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyBindingDiscussion), I can't see why it isn't working. Any thoughts?

Comment: I tried the fix I mentioned in my answer on an archlinux guest and I was unable to get C-F12 to work.  However changing to just F12 did work.  This may be a distro specific bug.  Would love to hear if you get this working.

Comment: @vschum: Using Gilles' version of the `(eval-after-load)` approach seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C mode (and specifically the `c-mode-map` variable) is provided by a package called `cc-mode`, not `c-mode`.

```
(eval-after-load 'cc-mode
  '(define-key c-mode-map (kbd "C-<f12>") 'compile))
```

For your other method, as [vschum has already answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18288/having-trouble-with-mode-specific-emacs-keybinding/18289#18289), you're missing the argument list in your `defun`. Furthermore, `c-mode-common-hook` isn't the right place for this: it's executed each time you enter C mode. The right time to add your binding is when C mode loads; you can do that either through the general `eval-after-load` mechanism as above, or through `c-initialization-hook`:

```
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  (define-key c-mode-map (kbd "C-<f12>") 'compile))
(add-hook 'c-initialization-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got a typo.  You're missing the argument definition for the defun.  In this case, since the function my-c-mode-common-hook doesn't take any arguments, add an empty set of parens after the function name.

```
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
    (define-key c-mode-map (kbd "C-<f12>") 'compile))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```